# TFRecords in a custom DataGenerator

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets, tfrecord, tf.data.dataset

I am doing an LSTM model in which samples have different number of time steps. I want to optimise my code and performance so I do not want to use masking, but I want to write a generator that will group automatically the batches with the same number of steps. My idea is the following:

1. For each possible sequence length (ranges from 1-365) create a TFRecord dataset which will have only the samples with that length
2. In each generator loop, randomly choose sequence length, and take the batch of data from corresponding TFRecord dataset. One option is to read in batches from this TFRecord dataset until it is depleted - this is preferrable if it is costly to open and close TFRecord dataset multiple times.
3. Otherwise, if it is not costly to open and close TFRecord dataset, and read from the middle, we can randomly choose sequence length for each batch (sounds more robust)

I was able to implement this logic with .csvs (i.e. one csv for files having fixed sequence lengths) following this example, [https://stanford.edu/~shervine/blog/keras-how-to-generate-data-on-the-fly](https://stanford.edu/%7Eshervine/blog/keras-how-to-generate-data-on-the-fly), but I am wondering if I can gain more performance if I would do this with the TFRecords. However, I couldn't find any resources that would teach me how to use them with this degree of flexibility.

Can anybody point me in the right direction here?

Thanks!

Comment: How large is your dataset?

Comment: 50gb, applications in the future might have more so I am looking for a scalable solution

Comment: Ok, so have you tried your idea?

Comment: I did with .csvs. I never worked with TFRecords, so am wondering if it makes sense to transition to them, since it is not the usual application, and if generally this sounds like the best direction to follow.

For example, I keep track of how much I read of the .csv file (so I truncate the remainder, since each batch has to have the same no of examples). I am not sure if I can do this with TfRecords. If there is a function batch(dataset1,dataset2) that would efficiently take batches guaranteeing that each batch is from one dataset, that would be exactly what I am looking for.